# Compute the Lambert W function

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Your challenge is to compute the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). \$W(x)\$ is defined to be the real value(s) \$y\$ such that

$$y = W(x) \text{ if } x = ye^y$$

where \$e = 2.718281828...\$ is [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

Sometimes, \$y\$ may not be real.

#### Examples

```
W(-1) = non-real
W(-0.1) = -0.11183, -3.57715
W(1) = 0.56714
W(2) = 0.85261
```

Here's a quick graph of what this function looks like.

[image]

---

#### Rules

Your goal is to take an input and output either nothing, 1 solution, or 2 solutions, out to 5 significant figs. You should expect float inputs within the reasonable range of `-100..100`.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: A note about Lambert W function: there is no solution for `x < -1/e`, two solutions for `-1/e < x < 0`, and one solution for `x == -1/e` or `x >= 0`.

Comment: 5 places after the decimal, or 5 significant figures? Since W^-1(x) tends to negative infinity when x->0-, it is hard to get 5 places after the decimal.

Comment: If one input should give _two_ values, this is not a function

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sure, though the `non-real` output should be reasonable.

Comment: @ColeraSu Fixed.

Comment: @LuisMendo It's a [multivalued 'function'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function).

Comment: I think a nice way to handle multiple solutions is the output being a list of reals, containing 0, 1, or 2 values. Would this be allowed?

Comment: @xnor Sounds like a great idea. Editting.

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```matlab
@(x)(y=lambertw(-1:0,x))(~imag(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0JTo9I2JzE3KbWopFxD19DKQKdCU1OjLjM3MV2jUlPzf5qGoSZXmoaugZ6h5v//IAoA)

I solved this in 10 different ways without the builtin, but I couldn't get the solution for both the `-1` branch and the `0`-branch. I wasn't able to solve this without resorting to the builtin `lambertw` function. Even though it uses a builtin, it's far from straightforward.

`lambertw` will only give out one value by default, namely the **W0(x)**, unless otherwise specified. The problem arises when we specifies that we want two values, both **W0(x)** and **W-1(x)**. If this is the case, and **x>=0**, it will return one real and one complex result.

We therefore have to specify that we only want the results where the imaginary part of the result is zero.

#### Breakdown:

```matlab
@(x)                              % Anonymous function that takes x as input
    (y=lambertw(-1:0,x))          % The lambertw function, with both the -1 and 0 branches
                        (~imag(y))  % Index, where the elements with imag(y)=0 is true
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>98</s> <s>86</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen

```
žr(zV"Ðžrsm*I-d"UY‹iõë∞.ΔX.V}®s‚ΔDÅAX.Vǝ}н,0‹i∞.Δ(X.V}(®‚ΔDÅAX.V≠ǝ}IYÊiн,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4ijaowpcMTgIziXC1P3RSl0MhHDTszD289vPpRxzy9c1Mi9MJqD60rftQw69wUl8OtjkD@8bm1F/bqGIDUQdRogBRpHFqHrOhR5wKgOs/Iw12ZQMX//@sa6BkCAA)

Explanation:

(I will let f(x)=x*e^x)

```
žr(zV"Ðžrsm*I-d"U #Let Y=-1/e,X=str(ÐYsm*I-d) to save characters in the future

Y‹iõ              #if input<-1/e: print empty string

ë∞.ΔX.V}          #else: find least int k>=1 such that f(k)>=0 (evaluates string X as though it were a function)

®s‚               #make list [-1,k]

ΔDÅAX.Vǝ}         #find root of f(x)-input in the interval [-1,k] using bisection method

                  #actually this outputs a list with 2 numbers which will be very close to each other, which represents the interval in which the root lies

                  #e.g. the list [-3.00001,-3] would represent the interval [-3.00001,-3]

н,                #print the first item of the list; stack is currently empty

0‹i               #if input<0:

∞.Δ(X.V}(         #find greatest int k<=-1 such that f(k)>=0

®‚                #make list [k,-1]

ΔDÅAX.V≠ǝ}        #find root of f(x)-input in the interval [k,-1] using bisection method

                  #again, this outputs a list rather than a single number

IYÊiн,            #if input!=-1/e, print that root (done so that "-1" is not printed twice)
```

Visualization of the program's indentation:

```
žr(zV"Ðžrsm*I-d"UY‹iõë∞.ΔX.V}®s‚ΔDÅAX.Vǝ}н,0‹i∞.Δ(X.V}(®‚ΔDÅAX.V≠ǝ}IYÊiн,
                   {    {   }   {       }    {  {    }   {        }   {
```

Comment: I'm sure this can be golfed some more, but here is [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6iMKXDEyKLc7U8dVOUQiM1qh417Mw8vNX@8OpHHfP0zk2J0AurPbSu@FHDrHNTXA63OgL5x@fWXtirYwBSCFGjAVKkcWgdsqJHnQuA6jyBBh7uygQq//9f10DPEAA) by replacing both `1(` with `®` ([relevant 05AB1E tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96417/52210)), and putting `ÐYsm*I-d` inside a string variable at the start, so we can use it four times with `.V`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 131 bytes

```
->x{y,z,e,l=1,-1,Math::E,->t{Math::log t};100.times{z=x<0&&x>-1/e ?l[x/z]:p;y=x<-1/e ?"non-real":x>e ?l[x/y]:x*e**-y};p y;z&&(p z)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpPC8IgHEC/iuwgNfxtSjdNO3XsEwwPC1wFtsky8A9@divW6T0eb31fY51kBRVyJIkYYiUjwMhl9HfOzwSUz5vb5YZ8EYzSzj@e5pWTDEeKcVDAeoNOdgh90tyJ@O1bauZlhtWMtuFB/ZeoeWhN20IswqEoEsY7h9K@1GkA2h10rT98AA)

Basically applies fixed-point iteration 100 times, as partially explained in [Lambert W function aproximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2187158).

Comment: Why non-competing?

Comment: Marking a submission non-competing does not make it valid. If your submission is invalid, please edit it to make it valid or delete it altogether. [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/60043).

Comment: Actually the only non-competing reason I have seen is language postdate the challenge. In other cases I often see they are deleted or competing. / Well, apply the fixed-point iteration is a valid way to compute the function, but only if you can prove that it is good enough (to your own requirement).

Comment: @JungHwanMin My submission is valid, I just marked it non-competing because, well, I didn't want to compete. I suppose that in itself is not a valid reason :P

Answer (score 1):

## C, 101 + 2 (`-lm`) bytes

Returns how many real solutions, and store them in an array.

This one is very slow, since it uses a brute-force approach to find roots. It handles up to x = 9e<sup>9</sup>.

```c
f(a,b,p,t,c,x)float*b,a,x;{for(p=a<0,c=0,x=-50;x<9;x+=2e-6,p=t)(t=x*exp(x)>a)^p?b[c++]=x:0;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBta8MgEMdfx09xZGxoY4rZQ8dm7D5I6cDY2Ap5kMQyoXQffdnZF5vInfy8//88TXk0Zlks1bzhngdueGS2G3VYNVzzKC92nKhXuhbcKMGjKl@EjPWbjIV6bMsN9yowGlRctdHTyLaaffqPZmeKYq/iu5BTG87TAEZelzs3mO58aKHudTitT1vyT@ZwcGNCxA0Beu0GysiFZLe3gB7mXSX2HLQkWSoImL9OrmuBfs9GD5bm9zbn8KAZA5RlfsKyRA@AOICCNGMyYgy1GY4FNDk5vBISU42m4IqCwZ/WJm3q7fY3kT@HmeZ5Ol/JdSnF@plgeNqkWJGywg8hgiAhFakEbkFeBa4fYzt9nJey638B)

## C, <s>148</s> 146 + 2 (`-lm`) bytes

This function returns how many real solutions, and store them in the given pointers.

Use binary search to find a solution. It handles up to about x = 10<sup>8</sup>.

```c
#define h(x)99;for(l=-1;x=(l+r)/2,fabs(l-r)>1e-6;)x*exp(x)>a?r=x:(l=x);
f(a,b,c,l,r)float*b,*c,a,l,r;{r=h(*b)r=-h(*c)return-1/exp(1)>a?0:a<0?2:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDRasMgFH2OXyEpK5pqq9koa9Ok33JjtBFsWoxlgdJ9@jLtw8YYeO@Rc849clX8pNQ8Lzpt7KBxTya621Xm4omruaymmriVp5uSGWhH4rinjdR8W9Gp0NM1uhs4@nraR/tEK2QIsJYp5pinxl0gFC0rFINEVHdf96Roqa95REW9Djc/cLlJSTIliT0cxLHcy@oxL@yg3K3T@HCG0K/7Bv0yY@jsJVHIDgGfwQ6EojvKnk9ikAxDGatCWdJDxI/eOo3J56hgMCR/MTnDS6AUx6ns6qMtsR2OdKjTFsuYsoSSxqWyzBpMAm6woPjHa5IX5B9d/tPLp369hZHkebo/0GPmYv2GYnvdpi4RL@OXIoEigySSIp5niQR69f6ljIPTOHN3/gY)

Answer (score 1):

## Casio BASIC, 192 Bytes

A port of [My 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203664/94333)

```
?→X
""
If X≥-e^-1
    Then 0→R
    While Re^R<X
        Isz R
    WhileEnd
    -1→L
    While Re^R>X
        .5(L+R→M
        If Me^M<X
            Then M→L
            Else M→R
        IfEnd
    WhileEnd
    If X<0
        Then M◢
        While Le^L<X
            Dsz L
        WhileEnd
        While Le^L≠X
            .5(L+R→M
            If Me^M<X
                Then M→R
                Else M→L
            IfEnd
        WhileEnd
        If M≠-1
            Then M
```

Note that indents are actually not supported; I added them for legibility.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 144 bytes

```forth
: N 99 for fover fover fnegate fexp f* fover 2e f** f+ fswap 1e f+ f/ next f. ;
: f fdup 0e -1e fexp f- f> if 0e N fdup f0< if -2e N then then ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNEoIwDIX3nOKtcYLQHeB4BO7AaB64qR2syO1rK8VF3s@XSfhc/CwTk4XQYUDbIrY4q/7V6jR6BXVzYJmpiaCM5QS@PqNDo798htXNgxX6ogPB@9uhVkhzPBDwigcTHPY160sCYhLxs9pd@pBucFsKk10OIFVO4Qs)

Being stuck with the floating-point stack hurts a lot (with all the `f`-prefixes), but I guess it's pretty good score for a non-built-in after all.

Uses 100 iterations of Newton's method [described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060824060948/http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/lambertw.html): given a previous estimate of \$w=W(x)\$, the next estimate \$w'\$ is calculated using the formula

$$
w' = \frac{xe^{-w}+w^2}{w+1}
$$

I simplified the starting points for the golf: starting at 0 for primary branch (if \$x \ge -1/e\$) and -2 (inflection point) for secondary branch (if \$-1/e \le x < 0\$) should suffice theoretically.

```forth
: N ( x w -- x )
  99 for                        \ ( x w ) run Newton's method 100 times...
    fover fover fnegate fexp f* \ ( x w x*e^-w )
    fover 2e f** f+             \ ( x w x*e^-w+ww )
    fswap 1e f+ f/              \ ( x (x*e^-w+ww)/(w+1) )
  next
  f.     \ Print the resulting w
;
: f ( x -- )
  fdup 0e -1e fexp f-  \ ( x x -1/e )
  f> if                \ ( x ) if less than -1/e, no solution
    0e N               \ ( x ) print primary solution
    fdup f0< if        \ ( x ) if less than 0, two solutions
      -2e N f.         \ ( x ) print secondary solution
    then
  then
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
x/.NSolve[#==E^x x,x,Reals]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8b9CX88vOD@nLDVa2dbWNa5CoUKnQicoNTGnOFbtv6Y1V0BRZl6JQ1q0roGeYex/AA)

Returns `x` for no-solution.

This function should give all solutions because `NSolve` algorithm uses inverse functions, and there is a built-in inverse function of `x = y*(e^y)` called `ProductLog`.

#### Explanation

```
#==E^x x
```

Equation `<input> = e^x * x`

```
NSolve[ ... ,x,Reals]
```

Find solutions in the domain of real numbers.

```
x/.
```

Replace `x` with the solutions.

#### Alternative version, 35 bytes

```
N@ProductLog[{-1,0},#]~Cases~_Real&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8d/PIaAoP6U0ucQnPz26WtdQx6BWRzm2zjmxOLW4Lj4oNTFH7b@mNVdAUWZeiUNatK6BnmHsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 258 bytes

```python
e,f,X,R,L=2.7182818,lambda x:x*e**x,float(input()),0,-1
if X>=-1/e:
 while f(R)<X:R+=1
 while f(R)>X:
  M=(L+R)/2
  if f(M)<X:L=M
  else:R=M
 print(M)
 if X<0:
  while f(L)<X:L-=1
  while f(L)!=X:
   M=(L+R)/2
   if f(M)<X:R=M
   else:L=M
  if M!=-1:print(M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NDoIwEITvPEW5FVh@igdJQ3mCcumpV4xtaFKBKEZ8emxRErzN7s58s9N77sfhtK4KNEgQwFmZnUlVVqQC290u1w4tdIlVHC@g7djN2AzTc8ZRBAWkJDAayYalJFc0QK/eWIU0FlEtqUgYOa4a6RyoZZgnIspLp11W49Z7OWvdrOxDUeHldDfD7E6B98i68MmdxLdA6uGHXcg2/B//ULBRfw3fMndrQ/c43bvWNS0y8gE)

A port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203664/94333)

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](http://sagemath.org), 39 bytes

```python
lambda z:[lambert_w(l,z)for l in[0,-1]]
```

[Try it on SageCell!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs43hyknMTUpJVKiyigaxUotK4ss1cnSqNNPyixRyFDLzog10dA1jY7m40jR0DfQMNQHM-Q_a&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)